# Getting the index of a list and display in error message during validation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have a validation rule as follows. I'm using the **validate** method via the **ValidateRequests** trait.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'entries'                 => 'required|max:5',
    'entries.*.name'          => 'required',
    'entries.*.email'         => 'required|email',
    'entries.*.mobile_number' => 'required'
]);
```

And these are some sample error messages that I've encountered.

```
[
    'entries.0.name'  => ['The entries.0.name is required.'],
    'entries.1.email' => ['The entries.1.email must be a valid email address.']
]
```

Is there a way to modify the message to these by using only the validation.php in modifying such messages?

```
[
    'entries.0.name'  => ['Line 0 - The name is required.'],
    'entries.1.email' => ['Line 1 - The email must be a valid email address.']
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize the error message then you can do it as:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                        'entries'                 => 'required|max:5',
                        'entries.*.name'          => 'required',
                        'entries.*.email'         => 'required|email',
                        'entries.*.mobile_number' => 'required'
                    ]);

$validator->setAttributeNames([
            'entries.*.name'          => 'name',
            'entries.*.email'         => 'email',
            'entries.*.mobile_number' => 'mobile number'
        ]);

$errors = $validation->errors()->all();
foreach ($errors as $key => $error) {
    $errors[$key] = "Line {$key} - $error";
}

// dd($errors);

if($validation->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($errors());
}
```

Comment: But still, 'entries.<index>.<attribute>' will still appear because the error message will print as "Line 0 - The entries.0.name field is required.' And I only want to use the validate method from the ValidateRequests trait. This can only mean that I'll re-implement it by using your method and imitate what the existing validate method returns if there are errors during validation.

Comment: The `setAttributeNames` function will replace all entries.<index>.<attribute> according to the array passed. And yes you have to do re-implement it, there is no straightforward solution.